# DBNull.Value being saved as Empty String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

this is my method below, this method is attached to datasource which is attached to ASPXGridview. My issues is that even though "N/A" is being passed for 'Language' to this SP, sometimes in the database it gets saved as an empty string. This doesnt happen all the time...

Any ideas as to why this could be getting saved as an empty string?

```
    public static void MaintainConfig(int ID, int ConfigVersionID, string Key, string Value, string Description, string Language)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = xxxServicesConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MaintainConfig", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@configID", ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@configVersionID", ConfigVersionID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", Key);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Description);
        if (Language == "N/A") //if the user wants to remove the language
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", Language);
        }

        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            if (sqlEx.Number == 50000)
            {
                throw sqlEx;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Database error occured");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Database error occured");
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would change `if (Language == null)` with `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Language))`; btw, you should test for empty values in your sproc

Comment: In the code above, an empty string WILL be saved into the database.

Comment: @RubensFarias +1. Or even better: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have debugged, almost all of the time it works perfectly but on the odd ocassion it doesnt work. Dont understand why it would be empty string

Comment: @PaoloFalabella it is never null, the drop down list i have to select the values from doesnt have null in it, that if statement was just extra precasution.

Comment: @user2991718 it may be not null but an empty string or one/more whitespaces. In case Language is an empty string your current code goes to the "else" branch and inserts the empty string in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1 :**  Instead of Comparing with `NULL` use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` function to do that.

**Replace this :**

```
else if (Language == null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
        }
```

**With following :**

```
else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Language.Trim()))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
        }
```

**Step2:**  Trim the values before comparing :

**Replace this :**

```
if (Language == "N/A") //if the user wants to remove the language
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
        }
```

**With following :**

```
if (Language.Trim().Equals("N/A")) //if the user wants to remove the language
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
        }
```

**final Solution :** if string contains `NULL`  then `Trim()`
 throws Exception hence Check for `NULL` before Trimming the values.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Language))
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
}

else if(Language.Trim().Equals("N/A"))
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
}

else if(Language.Trim().Equals(""))
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", Language);
}
```

Comment: What will the Language.Trim() do?

Comment: it will remove the spaces(leading and trailing) in Language variable.

Comment: trim the values before comapring ,see my edited answer hope it solves your problem,

Comment: `Language.Trim()` sill throw an exception if `Language` is null

Comment: it happens when Language contains NULL so you can do trim() after checking for null. see my edited answer with "final solution" section.

Answer (score 0):

`Language` probably comes as empty string in the first place.

Change `if (Language == null)` to `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Language))`

You can use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` if you want to exclude spaces...

Answer (score 0):

When `Language` is en empty string, it is saved as such.

Change the line

```
if (Language == null)
```

to

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Language))
```

Comment: that if statement isnt the issue tho, issue is sometimes it saves as null other times it saves as empty string...